# Is there a special name for the following type of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Weighted graphs such that if $x$ and $y$ are nodes in the graph, and $p$ and $p'$ are two paths in the graph between $x$ and $y$, then the weight of $p$ equals the weight of $p'$.

Comment: If I were to invent a name, I’d call it a [potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_potential) graph.

Comment: It's not the same concept, in particular because your question makes sense only for digraphs and these are undirected, but this reminds me a bit of distance-hereditary graphs, graphs in which all induced paths between the same two vertices have the same (unweighted) length.

Comment: For undirected graphs, graphs with this property cannot contain cycle. Suppose they do and there's two neighboring vertices $s$ and $t$. Then by the property the edge $e(s,t)$ and the path from $s$ to $t$ that uses the rest of the cycle must have equal weight, say $w$. Now consider the vertex next to t in the cycle, say u and let $w'$ be the weight of the t-u edge. Then the one s-u path has weight w+w' and the other has weight w-w', thus unless w'=0, the property does not hold.

Comment: @chazisop, the *unless* of your contradiction can hold, so really the statement should be that any cycle in an undirected graph with this property must contain only edges of weight 0.

Comment: The statement should be just that the *sum* of edge weights along any cycle is $0$. And if we further state it for undirected cycles, where weights of edges traversed in the wrong direction are negated, then this is *equivalent* to the original condition.

Comment: The sum along a cycle being $0$ implies that all weights are $0$ (unless the weights are such that $2=0$): For any edge $l$ on a cycle $C$, we have both $w(l)=w(C\setminus l)$ from OP's condition, and $w(l)=-w(C\setminus l)$ from $w(C)=0$.

Comment: It seems we are talking past each other. I was considering directed graphs. While the OP somewhat suggests undirected graphs, this makes no sense whatsoever, as the condition then implies all weights are 0 (for any edge e, compare it with the path that traverses e there, back, and there again).

Comment: For directed graphs, the condition certainly doesn't imply all edges are 0, even if there are cycles: take e.g. the two-node graph where the edge in one direction has weight 1, and in the opposite direction weight $-1$.